# using pmap from purrr to iterate over lists of lists with time series functions

Tags: r, time-series, purrr

I wrote the following function *mape_fcn* to calculate the accuracy of a time series forecast, as follows:

```
library(forecast)
mape_fcn <- function(fcn, trn, tst, h) {
   fcst <- forecast(fcn(trn), h = h) # calculates a forecast using the training data
   fcst_mean <- as.numeric(fcst$mean) # converts the forecast to a numeric value
   mape <- sum(abs(fcst_mean - tst))/sum(tst) # calculates the weighted MAPE (Mean Absolute Percentage Error) of this forecast on the training data to the test data
   mape
}
```

where *fcn* is the time series function tested, *trn* is the time series training data (all but the last *h* observations), *tst* is the time series test data that has been withheld to test the accuracy of the forecast, and *h* is the horizon of the forecast.

I have used this function with *pmap* from the *purrr* library to calculate the MAPEs of various functions from the *forecast* library over one training and one test data set, as follows.

```
library(purrr)
library(forecast)

fcns <- list(auto.arima, nnetar, tbats)
trainlstsku1 <- list(trainsku1)
testlstsku1 <- list(testsku1)
pmap(list(fcns, trainlstsku1, testlstsku1, 12), mape_fcn)
```

Output below is the MAPEs of the various functions (decimals, not percents).

```
# [[1]]
# [1] 0.4552366
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 0.3576489
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 0.4256295
```

I would like to extend this to iterate over two training and two test sets, respectively, as I have tried below.

```
trainlstsample <- list(list(trainsku1, trainsku2))
testlstsample <- list(list(testsku1, testsku2))
pmap(list(fcns, trainlstsample, testlstsample, 12), mape_fcn)
```

So for each of the data sets (sku1 and sku2), I want to see MAPEs for the three functions listed. There would be 6 MAPE outputs.

However this is the error I get:

```
 Error in is.constant(x) : 
    (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
    Called from: is.constant(x)
```

Here are the corresponding data with code to convert the vectors to *ts* objects. (I did not share as *ts* objects due to formatting issues.) Although not usually advised, I am sharing all the data since the data sets are not large, and sufficient observations are necessary for the forecasting functions. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
trainsku1 <- ts( c(31900, 48000, 16000, 0, 16000, 48000, 96000, 0, 0, 31900, 32000, 63000, 63600, 32000, 0, 0, 0, 63100, 63300, 126500, 32000, 96000, 32000, 61400, 30000, 32000, 63700, 63700, 0, 0, 92800, 29800, 0, 0, 61800, 76500, 47800, 107600, 45200, 31700, 14600, 63600, 79500, 31900, 16000, 48000, 48000, 48000), start = c(2013, 8), frequency = 12)  
testsku1 <- ts( c(16000, 48000, 32000, 16000, 48000, 64000, 111900, 48000, 16000, 62900, 31300, 32000), start = c(2017, 8), frequency = 12)
trainsku2 <- ts( c(56250, 90000, 108900, 96000, 0, 0, 0, 86400, 32400, 43200, 162000, 216000, 64800, 97200, 75600, 75600, 64800, 64800, 0, 0, 0, 0, 108000, 54000, 0, 0, 43200, 43200, 0, 0, 43200, 43200, 43200, 0, 108000, 43200, 43200), start = c(2014, 6), frequency = 12)
testsku2 <- ts( c(54000, 43200, 43200, 0, 0, 97200, 0, 54000, 0, 54000, 129600, 0, start = c(2017, 7), frequency = 12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your definition of `trainlstsample` and `testlstsample` to be nested lists:

```
trainlstsample <- list(list(trainsku1), list(trainsku2))
testlstsample <- list(list(testsku1), list(testsku2))
```

Then you can nest your `pmap` call inside a `map2` call that iterates over those:

```
map2( .x = trainlstsample, .y = testlstsample,
    ~pmap(list(fcns, .x, .y, 12), mape_fcn) )
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] 0.4552366

# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] 0.364658

# [[1]][[3]]
# [1] 0.4256295

# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] 0.7338271

# [[2]][[2]]
# [1] 1.055283

# [[2]][[3]]
# [1] 0.6990185
```

Comment: innovative solution; thanks! I appreciate your correcting some code/formatting as well.